# Ambiguity resolution and rvalue/lvalue conversion

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, move-semantics

I wrote this short test code

```
 # include <iostream>
 using std::cout;

struct P
{
  P()
   {cout << "I'm P::P()\n";};
  P(const P& p)
   {cout << "I'm P::P(const P&)\n";}
  P(P&& p)
   {cout << "I'm P::P(P&&)\n";}
};

int main()
{
  P pa, pe(pa);
  P pi((P(pa))), // this should be an object declaration
    pu(std::move(pa)); // as well as this one
  P po(P(pa)); // this is, instead, a function declaration
}
```

and I got the following output

```
I'm P::P()
I'm P::P(const P&)
I'm P::P(const P&)
I'm P::P(P&&)
```

I have understood all but the third line of output, coming from the instantiation of the `pi` object: why is the copy constructor being called and not the move constructor as it happens for the `pu` object?

Shouldn't the `P(pa)` parameter be an unnamed non-const rvalue? How can it be bound to a lvalue reference? Or the third line comes from the copy
constructor instantiating the parameter itself? In this case who constructs `pi` ? Is there some kind of optimization ?

Comment: `const` lvalue references *can* bind to temporaries. Is that what's confusing you?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12953127/what-are-copy-elision-and-return-value-optimization

Comment: What Holt said. `(P(pa))` skips the creation of the temporary, and instead initializes `pi` directly from `pa`, which is an lvalue.

Comment: Note: You might use `{}` to avoid vexing parse.

Comment: I don't think `const` is relevant because the same output is obtained also removing the `const` qualifier from the copy constructor's signature. Rather it seems to be a "move elision" since, compiling with the `--no-elide-constructors` option the move constructor appears to be called twice.